# Network Troubles - Cannot Ping Windows PC

Tags: networking, server, dns

I've seen a lot of similar questions but nothing seems to quite describe my situation.

I have a few devices on my network, LinuxPC, WindowsPC, Laptop, and NAS.

From my LinuxPc running Ubunutu 18.04 I can successfully ping Laptop and NAS:

```
ping Laptop
PING LAPTOP (192.168.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from LAPTOP.local (192.168.1.5): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.04 ms

ping NAS
PING NAS (192.168.1.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from NAS.local (192.168.1.12): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.04 ms
```

However, when I try to ping the WindowsPc it fails

```
ping WindowsPc
ping: WindowsPc: System error
```

Now, it's not that WindowsPc isn't the correct type.  If I ping a random name that doesn't exist - `ping asdfasdf` - I get a different message entirely: `ping: asdfasdf: Name or service not known`

I also thought it might be a firewall issue, but if I use my Windows Laptop, I can ping WindowsPC without any trouble.  And if I ping the IP address directly from my Linux PC it works great.

So every other device on the network can access WindowsPC by name, except Ubuntu.

I've done things like install `netbind` and added 'wins' to my /etc/nsswitch.conf file and that allowed me to ping everything else.  But not my PC.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you `dig WindowsPC` as give the output, where are you defining the names? Can you ping WindowsPC by IP address? Can you access services on WindowsPC, is it just ICMP that aren't going through/coming back?

Comment: ipv4 vs ipv6 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the nsslib-resolve package.  That may be all that's needed.  Your /etc/nsswitch.conf would have a hosts line like:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

I don't have a "wins" anywhere there and it works just fine.  The /etc/resolv ends with a search line, from my isp/gateway but you look like yours should say "search local" f rom your ping results.